# Bi-directional reference from sub class

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

Simply put I have the following EMF model:

`Step`

- successor
- predecessor

`ForkStep` extends `Step`

- alternateSuccessor

Now there is a bi-directional reference between the `successor` and its `predecessor` - No problem so far.

The tricky part is: How to create a bi-directional reference from `alternateSuccessor` to its super-class `predecessor`?

Normally each step can only have one predecessor and one successor. But a fork may have two successors (`successor` and `alternateSuccessor`).

If I now go on and create a bi-directional reference, EMF generates a new attribute in the super class, which seems not quite right?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot express this with just plain EMF. What you can do is at least introduce OCL constraint to keep your model consistent.

Comment: I feared so. I found a workaround, but I am curious, what exactly do you mean with OCL constraint?

Comment: Ok, maybe my comment wasn't clear. Therefore I added an answer to your question. Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be understood in two ways:

1. Given a model, how can we detect which step is "default" and which is "fork".
2. How can we enforce that users are only able to create "default" steps (single successor) or "fork" steps (multiple successors).

### Case #1:

You need a single class `Step` where you introduce a property `isForkStep`.
The value of this property will be derived using OCL as follows: `successor->size() > 1`.

First, I created the meta-model (called the file `My.ecore`) according to your example. I had to add a `Scenario` class acting as a container for steps.
The meta-model looks as follows:
[image]

Then, I opened the `My.ecore` file using "OCLinEcore editor" and added the OCL code to the `isForkStep` property.

```
package test : test = 'test'
{
    class Scenario {
        property steps : Step[*] { ordered composes };
    }
    class Step {
        attribute stepId : String { id };
        attribute isForkStep : Boolean {
            derivation: successor->size() > 1;
        }
        property predecessor#successor : Step[?];
        property successor#predecessor : Step[*] { ordered };
    }
}
```

Then, I tested my new meta-model by creating a "dynamic instance" from `Scenario` where I created 4 steps. Here is a screenshot from that shows the `Scenario` instance together with 4 steps. As you can see in the "Properties" view, `Step 1` has the property "Is Fork Step" set to `true` (by clicking to the other steps, you would see `false`).
[image]

### Case #2:

Here, I modeled the situation differently. I created an interface `Step` and two implementation classes - `DefaultStep` and `ForkStep`.
Then, I added different OCL constraints to both classes.

- DefaultStep: `successor->size() <= 1`
- ForkStep: `successor->size() >= 2`

Note: I might also use `successor->size() >= 2 or successor->size() = 0` to allow ForkSteps without successors.

The meta-model looks like this:
[image]

There are many other ways how this can be implemented.
For example, you can use Java instead of OCL, or you can model the situation differently.

Btw. a nice slideshow about OCL in EMF can be found here:
http://www.slideshare.net/EdWillink/enriching-withocl

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer with the link! But unfortunately that is not what I hoped for.. Your solution puts no constraint on how many successors a step may have (Default Step: 1 and the Fork Step: any).

Comment: I updated my answer because I misunderstood your question before. Now, the model has two classes as you originally requested and the invariants are enforced by OCL. It works without using Java and you can use it immediately in the Ecore tree editor by turning on "Live Validation".

Comment: Yes, that answers my question and is somewhat correct. I tried this and it works, but because the application is standalone I had to import about 6MB of dependencies which seems a bit off. But that is another story. Thanks for your time and your answer!